# Google Sheets regex - sum a column based on text in the cell

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have a cell that can contain multiple strings, but the strings have consistent formatting:
Example, each row is the content of a cell

```
12km run, 2km swim, 15km bike
6km run, 10km bike
3km swim
15km run, 1km swim
```

etc.

Now, I want to sum the column, but conditionally depending on what string the numerical belongs to, so that I can have 3 sum categories for run, swim and bike, ie. wanted output in the above case would be:

```
33km run
25km bike
6km swim
```

Any ideas how to construct a function that can sum a column according to these conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your requirement, try below formula, assuming you have data in **Column A**

For Run:

```
=Sum(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+.run)"),"\D",""))),""))&"km run"
```

For Swim:

```
=Sum(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+.swim)"),"\D",""))),""))&"km swim"
```

For Bike:

```
=Sum(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+.bike)"),"\D",""))),""))&"km bike"
```

And If you need all in one cell

```
=Sum(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+.run)"),"\D",""))),""))&"km run, "&
Sum(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+.swim)"),"\D",""))),""))&"km swim, "
&Sum(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+.bike)"),"\D",""))),""))&"km bike"
```

[image]